# Updating a nested array using $indexOfArray and $slice in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using the following documents, we are able to do what we need to do which is essentially "re-parenting" a document that stores an array of ancestors like so:

```
db.getCollection("myarrays").insertOne({
    "myid": "A",
    "ancestors": [
         {
             "_id": "parent1",
             "type": "type1"
         },
         {
             "_id": "parent2",
             "type": "type1"
         },
         {
             "_id": "parent3",
             "type": "type1"
         }       
    ]
})
```

```
db.getCollection("myarrays").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "ancestors._id" : "parent2"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "ancestors" : { 
                    "$concatArrays" : [
                        [
                            { 
                                "_id" : "parent4", 
                                "type" : "type1"
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "_id" : "parent5", 
                                "type" : "type1"
                            }
                        ], 
                        { 
                            "$slice" : [
                                "$ancestors", 
                                { 
                                    "$add" : [
                                        { 
                                            "$indexOfArray" : [
                                                "$ancestors._id", 
                                                "parent2"
                                            ]
                                        }, 
                                        1.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$size" : [
                                        "$ancestors"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

This effectively finds any documents that are grandchildren of "parent2" and re-parents them to "parent5" (which itself is a child of "parent4"). The resulting document looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("61e9860d97f54a3cebb47e3d"), 
    "ancestors" : [
        {
            "_id" : "parent4", 
            "type" : "type1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "parent5", 
            "type" : "type1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "parent3", 
            "type" : "type1"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works great. However, I'm struggling to do the exact same thing in a case where `ancestors` is nested within another array:

```
db.getCollection("myarraysnested").insertOne(
    {
        "references": [
            { 
                "myid": "A",
                "ancestors": [
                     {
                         "_id": "parent1",
                         "type": "type1"
                     },
                     {
                         "_id": "parent2",
                         "type": "type1"
                     },
                     {
                         "_id": "parent3",
                         "type": "type1"
                     }       
                ]
            },
            { 
                "myid": "B",
                "ancestors": [
                     {
                         "_id": "parent4",
                         "type": "type1"
                     },
                     {
                         "_id": "parent5",
                         "type": "type1"
                     },
                     {
                         "_id": "parent3",
                         "type": "type1"
                     }       
                ]
            },
            { 
                "myid": "C",
                "ancestors": [
                     {
                         "_id": "parent0",
                         "type": "type1"
                     },
                     {
                         "_id": "parent1",
                         "type": "type1"
                     },
                     {
                         "_id": "parent2",
                         "type": "type1"
                     },
                     {
                         "_id": "parent6",
                         "type": "type2"
                     }       
                ]
            }
            
        ]
    }
)
```

The desired outcome would be that 2 of the 3 `references` elements that match an `ancestors` array containing an element with `_i` = to "parent2" would have their `ancestors` array updated to look just as the non-nested sample above looks resulting in the following output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("61e9860d97f54a3cebb47e3c"), 
    "references" : [
        {
            "myid" : "A", 
            "ancestors" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "parent4", 
                    "type" : "type1"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "parent5", 
                    "type" : "type1"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "parent3", 
                    "type" : "type1"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "myid" : "B", 
            "ancestors" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "parent4", 
                    "type" : "type1"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "parent5", 
                    "type" : "type1"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "parent3", 
                    "type" : "type1"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "myid" : "C", 
            "ancestors" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "parent4", 
                    "type" : "type1"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "parent5", 
                    "type" : "type1"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "parent6", 
                    "type" : "type2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried several iterations of using `$filter` and `$map` but can't quite get things correct for at the very least, finding the index of the element in the nested array that matches. I would prefer to avoid `$unwind` if possible but if not possible, that could work.

**Note: The pipeline is/will be used as part of an update statement to actually change the document so any limitations of the update pipeline style apply.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `$unwind` `references` for easier processing and reusing your working logic. Use `$cond` to conditionally perform your working logic on elements with `parent2`. Finally, `$group` to regroup the unwinded documents. Use `$merge` to update the aggregate result back to the collection.

```js
db.myarrays.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "references.ancestors._id": "parent2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$references"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "references.ancestors": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$in": [
              "parent2",
              "$references.ancestors._id"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              [
                {
                  "_id": "parent4",
                  "type": "type1"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "parent5",
                  "type": "type1"
                }
              ],
              {
                "$slice": [
                  "$references.ancestors",
                  {
                    "$add": [
                      {
                        "$indexOfArray": [
                          "$references.ancestors._id",
                          "parent2"
                        ]
                      },
                      1.0
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$size": [
                      "$references.ancestors"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "else": "$references.ancestors"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "references": {
        "$push": "$references"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "myarrays",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sQYW4hJ4cCt) for your reference. Note that Mongo playground is displaying only the result set, instead of the updated documents. Below is a screenshot of my local MongoDB run result. You should see there is an extra field `field` with value `to be kept` for the verification purpose that other fields are kept.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, an important part of my question was missed: "Note: The pipeline is/will be used as part of an update statement to actually change the document so any limitations of the update pipeline style apply."
  
`unwind` and `group` stages aren't allowed in updates :( Per [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the answer to add $merge for the update.

Comment: I'm a little leery of merging into the same collection as the docs call out some potential pitfalls with doing so but it works so thank you for that. One thing of note that you may want to edit your answer before I accept it is that "whenMatched" should be `{"$set": { "references": "$$new.references" }}` so that other fields can exist surrounding the array. Something I had left out for brevity.

Comment: @Tom simply use the `"whenMatched": "merge"` in the `$merge` and you should be good to go